# Vader's remains

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

It's clear that

> Kylo Ren

has Vader's burnt face mask.  He also has what appears to be ashes.

- Are they Vader's ashes?
- How did he get them?

Given that he has the mask, it seems implied that they are Vader's ashes.  Vader's body was burned on a pyre on Endor.  Is it safe to assume that Luke kept the ashes?

> Kylo woudn't even have been born yet at the time

Did Luke collect the face mask as well?  Why would he collect the mask?  It seems it is symbolic of Vader rather than as a memento of his now-redeemed father Anakin.

Comment: Pure speculation. But would you probably wouldn't want to leave them where anyone could get hold if then.

Comment: Maybe they were in an urn in Luke's flat and Someone swiped them on their way out the door ;)

Comment: He has a sister.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the new canon book "The Perfect Weapon" - a character is tasked

> with obtaining an item in a case, presumably taken from Endor post-battle. We do not learn what is in the case in the book but one could assume it was Vader's remains / parts.

In "Aftermath", there is a small scene where

> what is believed to be Vader's lightsaber is being sold

So there does seem to be an effort being made to collect Vader related items